# How to make a ship animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a ship animation (as per the image below)?

Which of these two technologies do I require CSS or Javascript?

[image]

Comment: If you mean, to animate an object around the screen, you should have a look to div elements and jQuery, which is a great and easy Javascript Framework with many examples that can help you to achieve that task

Comment: you may need css **and** javascript

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for free" place. Try something and if it doesn't work, ask a question. Also see, [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the animation of the floating ship hope you will learn something from it.

## HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
</div>
</div>

<div class="ocean"></div>
<div class="ocean-overlay"></div>
<div class="here-there">
    <div class="traslate">
        <div class="ship">
            <div class="bottom-1">
                <div class="bottom-1-top"></div>
                <div class="bottom-1-top-left"></div>
                <div class="bottom-1-top-right">
                    <div class="bottom-1-top-right-window"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ship-body">
                <div class="middle-window"></div>
                <div class="blue-strip-top"></div>
                <div class="blue-strip-bottom"></div>
                <div class="ship-body-top-back">
                    <div class="blue-strip-top-half"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="chimney-base">
                    <div class="chimney"></div>
                    <div class="chimney"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ship-body-top-front">
                <div class="top-antenna"></div>
                <div class="circular-base"></div>
                <div class="circular-base-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ship-body-top-front-mirror"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html , body {height:100%;}
body {
    background: #4297cd;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.ship {
    width:350px;
    height:20px;

    margin-left:5%;
    position:   absolute;
}
.ship { 
    -webkit-animation:floating-ship 3s aletrnate ;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,.5,.99,.54);
    -moz-animation:floating-ship 3s aletrnate ;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0,.5,.99,.54);
}
 @-webkit-keyframes floating-ship {
     from {-webkit-transform:rotate(4deg);}
     to {-webkit-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
 }
 @-moz-keyframes floating-ship {
     from {-moz-transform:rotate(4deg);}
     to {-moz-transform:rotate(-4deg);}
 }
.bottom-1 {
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:12px solid #54575c;
    border-left:16px solid transparent;
    width:250px;
    height:0px;
}
.bottom-1:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-8px;
    left:-7px;
    border-right:10px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid #fff;
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    width:276px;
    height:0px;
}
.bottom-1:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-11px;
    left:-8px;
    border-right:1px solid transparent;
    border-top:3px solid #e3001b;
    border-left:1px solid transparent;
    width:293px;
    height:0px;
}
.bottom-1-top {
    width:295px;
    height:5px;
    background:#e5e9ec;
    position:absolute;
    top:-16px;
    left:-8px;
}
.bottom-1-top:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    height:5px;
    width:20px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-40deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-40deg);
    background:#e5e9ec;
    right:-2px;
}
.bottom-1-top-left {
    width:60px;
    height:15px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-31px;
    left:-8px;
}
.bottom-1-top-left:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:15px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(50deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(50deg);
    background:#fff;
    right:-9px;
}
.bottom-1-top-left:before {
    content:'';
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#8a9295;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:5px;
    left:8px;
    box-shadow:14px 0 0 #8a9295 , 28px 0 0 #8a9295 , 42px 0 0 #8a9295   ;
}
.bottom-1-top-right {
    width:107px;
    height:15px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-31px;
    left:180px;
}
.bottom-1-top-right:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:15px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-50deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-50deg);
    background:#fff;
    left:-9px;
}
.bottom-1-top-right:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:15px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-50deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-50deg);
    background:#fff;
    right:-13px;
}
.ship-body {
    width:235px;
    height:40px;
    background:#ebebeb;
    position:absolute;
    top:-54px;
    left:14px;
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.1) inset;
}
.ship-body:before {
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    content:'';
    width:40px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-34deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-34deg);
    height:30px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}
.ship-body:after {
    position:absolute;
    right:-16px;
    content:'';
    width:40px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(44deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(44deg);
    height:30px;
    background:#ebebeb;
}
.blue-strip-top {
    background:#72a4c4;
    width:224px;
    height:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    z-index:1;
    left:8px;
}
.blue-strip-top:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    height:4px;
    left:-7px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-30deg);
}
.blue-strip-top:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    height:4px;
    right:-5px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(50deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(50deg);
}
.blue-strip-bottom {
    background:#72a4c4;
    width:240px;
    height:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:14px;
    z-index:1;
}
.blue-strip-bottom:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    height:4px;
    left:-5px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-30deg);
}
.blue-strip-bottom:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:10px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    height:4px;
    right:-5px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(50deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(50deg);
}
.ship-body-top-back {
    height:15px;
    width:60px;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ebebeb;
    top:-12px;
    left:8px;
}
.ship-body-top-back:before {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-34deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-34deg);
    background:#ebebeb;
    left:-5px;
}
.ship-body-top-back:after {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    content:'';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(43deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(43deg);
    background:#ebebeb;
    right:-8px;
}
.ship-body-top-front {
    position:absolute;
    width:40px;
    height:10px;
    background:#efefef;
    right:120px;
    top:-74px;
}
.ship-body-top-front:before {
    height:30px;
    width:14px;
    background:#efefef;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-40deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-40deg);
    left:-13px;
    z-index:-2;
}
.ship-body-top-front:after {
    height:10px;
    width:20px;
    background:#efefef;
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    -webkit-transform:skewX(44deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(44deg);
    right:-11px;
    z-index:-2;
}
.ship-body-top-front-mirror {
    background:#a5d4e4;
    width:40px;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-70px;
    right:125px;
    z-index:-4;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.ship-body-top-front-mirror:after {
    content:'';
    background:#a5d4e4;
    width:40px;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
    right:-16px;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(44deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(44deg);
    z-index:-4;
}
.blue-strip-top-half {
    width:80%;
    top:8px;
    z-index:1;
    height:4px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
}
.blue-strip-top-half:before {
    content:'';
    width:10px;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    height:4px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(-30deg);
    left:-4px;
}
.blue-strip-top-half:after {
    content:'';
    width:10px;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    height:4px;
    background:#72a4c4;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform:skewX(44deg);
    -moz-transform:skewX(44deg);
    right:-4px;
}
.top-antenna {
    width:8px;
    height:16px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:-16px;
    left:20px;
    -webkit-transform:SkewX(44deg);
    -moz-transform:SkewX(44deg);
}
.top-antenna:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:20px;
    height:4px;
    background:#fff;
    display:block;
    top:-4px;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-44deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: skewX(-44deg) !important;
    left: 2px;
}
.top-antenna:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff; 
    border-left: 2px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 2px solid transparent;
    display:block;
    top:-20px;
    right:5px;
    z-index:-1;
    left: 15px;
}
.circular-base {
    display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
width: 7px;
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.circular-base:before {
    display:block;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:-10px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 39%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 40%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(39%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(40%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), color-stop(41%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 39%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 39%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 39%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 39%,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 40%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 41%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );

}
.circular-base-1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:26px;
    height:4px;
    background:#fff;
    top:-4px;
    left:3px;
}
.circular-base-1:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #fff;
    top: -8px;
    left: 13px;
}
.chimney-base {
    width:60px;
    height:5px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-17px;
    left:9px;
}
.chimney {
    width:25px;
    height:10px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-left:5px;
}
.chimney:before {
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:6px;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:-6px;
}
.chimney:after {
    content:'';
    width:25px;
    height:6px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
}
.ocean {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    background:rgba(25,93,164,0.8);
    bottom:0;
}
.ocean-overlay {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    background:rgba(25,93,164,0.35);
    bottom:0;
    z-index:10;
    box-shadow:0 25px 25px rgba(25,93,164,0.5) inset;
}
.traslate {
    -webkit-animation:5s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite floating;
    -moz-animation:5s ease-in-out 0s normal none infinite floating;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;

}
@-webkit-keyframes floating {
    0% {
        bottom: 48px;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
    50% {
        bottom: 52px;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(-1deg);
        -webkit-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 48px;
        -webkit-transform:rotate(1deg) ;
        -webkit-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes floating {
    0% {
        bottom: 48px;
        -moz-transform:rotate(1deg);
        -moz-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
    50% {
        bottom: 52px;
        -moz-transform:rotate(-1deg);
        -moz-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 48px;
        -moz-transform:rotate(1deg) ;
        -moz-transform-origin:-20% -40%;
    }
}
.here-there {
    -webkit-animation:movenow 60s infinite ;
    -moz-animation:movenow 60s infinite ;
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    bottom:30px;

}
@-webkit-keyframes movenow {
    0%   {right:110%;}
    100% {right:0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes movenow {
    0%   {right:110%;}
    100% {right:0;}
}
.wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.bottom-1-top-right-window {
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ADB1B3 ;
    left:3px;
    z-index:1;
    top:5px;
    box-shadow:14px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 28px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 42px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 56px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 70px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 84px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 98px 0 0 #ADB1B3;
}
.middle-window {
    width:6px;
    height:6px;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ADB1B3 ;
    left:56px;
    z-index:1;
    bottom:6px;
    box-shadow:14px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 28px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 42px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 56px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 70px 0 0 #ADB1B3 , 84px 0 0 #ADB1B3 ;
}
```